# dust.js - can I use a helper to loop through a comma separated value?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm new to dust.js.

one of the values in a JSON object I'm working with is "foo,bar,baz". Can I write a helper to iterate through these values like a # section? Or is there another way to do that without preprocessing the JSON object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is definetly YES.
As logicless templating engine, dust.js handles all logic inside the helpers.
In your example it will suffice to just split the value, loop over the values while rendering your content and then return everything at the end of the function.

EXAMPLE:

```
function($, dust) {
    // helpers object
    var helpers = {
        'h_value' : function(chunk, ctx, bodies, params) {
            var values = ctx.current()
                            .value
                            .split(',');

            for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++) {
                chunk.write('<li>'+ values[i] +'</li>');
            }                
        }
    }

    // create a new base context
    // helpers will be part of context now
    var base = dust.makeBase(helpers);

    // this is only an example, you should work with a separate template file    
    var source = '{#sections}<ul>{#h_value}<li>{.}</li>{/h_value}</ul>{/sections}';
    // and template should be compiled on server side (in most cases)
    var compiled = dust.compile(source, 'test');
    dust.loadSource(compiled);

    var sectionsData = {
        sections : [
            { value : 'foo,bar,baz'},
            { value : 'bar,baz,foo'},
            { value : 'baz,foo,bar'}
        ] 
    };

    dust.render('test', base.push(sectionsData), function(err, content) {
        $('body').append(content); 
    });
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful, actually. I think I'm mostly unsure how to write my own helpers.

Comment: I'm kinda busy right now, but I will try to post a simple example as soon as possible. Stay tuned!

Comment: Here You go :) I did my best. One more advice try to read http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/ thoroughly. It's not perfect, but it helps at the beginning :) The best way to deal with helpers is to try to play with chunks, ctx, bodies and different sort of outputs. Then it's quite easy. Have fun and don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: ...and another thing ;) You can see I have named MY helper "h_value". I have used "h_" prefix because there is no way to distinct helper named "value" from a "value" key. Of course dust will handle this situation, but You or other developer can't tell the difference. This was the practice I have used in my former job.